# How do I get the output box back to the normal position in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio

Owing to a careless mouse drag, the output/error/search results area now occupies the entire screen, being selectable as one of the files in the tabs along the top.

Does anyone know how to get it back to the usual place; that is to say, at the foot of the code and not protruding into the file/properties area at the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the tab and click 'Dockable'. You can then drag the tool window to any place you like.

[image]